# Trying to filter results from a query using CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have 2 WP tables, 1st is the standard users table, the 2nd is an extra fields plugin. The 2nd table is constructed of the type with the fields user_id, field_id and value

I have constructed the following query to extract data from the 2nd table, but cannot work out how to filter the results based on the 'State' field.

Putting in a line WHERE `State` = 'SA' just throws up the Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'State' in 'where clause' Trying to add 'IF' statements into the CASE line doesn't work...  anyone got any ideas?

```
SELECT
        `wpty_users`.`user_login` AS `user_login`,
        `wpty_users`.`display_name` AS `display_name`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`FIELD_ID` = 8 THEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`VALUE` ELSE NULL END) AS `Club`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`FIELD_ID` = 9 THEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`VALUE` ELSE NULL END) AS `State`
 FROM
        `wpty_users`
        LEFT JOIN `wpty_cimy_uef_data` ON `wpty_users`.`ID` = `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`USER_ID`
    GROUP BY `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`USER_ID`
    ORDER BY `wpty_users`.`user_login`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `having`:

```
SELECT `wpty_users`.`user_login` AS `user_login`,
       `wpty_users`.`display_name` AS `display_name`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`FIELD_ID` = 8 THEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`VALUE` ELSE NULL END) AS `Club`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`FIELD_ID` = 9 THEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`VALUE` ELSE NULL END) AS `State`
 FROM `wpty_users` LEFT JOIN
      `wpty_cimy_uef_data`
       ON `wpty_users`.`ID` = `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`USER_ID`
GROUP BY `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`USER_ID`
HAVING State = 'SA'
ORDER BY `wpty_users`.`user_login`;
```

`HAVING` is the correct way to filter an aggregation query.

I would recommend simplifying the query as well:

```
SELECT u.user_loginl, u.display_name,
       MIN(CASE WHEN ud.FIELD_ID = 8 THEN ud.VALUE END) AS Club,
        MIN(CASE WHEN ud.FIELD_ID = 9 THEN ud.VALUE END) AS State
 FROM wpty_users u JOIN
      wpty_cimy_uef_data  ud
      ON u.ID = ud.USER_ID
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING State = 'SA'
ORDER BY u.user_login;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Backticks make the query harder to write and to read.
- You are requiring that there be a valid `state`, so an inner join is more appropriate than an outer join.
- The `GROUP BY` key should really be from the users table, because it is the unique identifier on that table and you are selecting other unaggregated columns from that table.

Comment: Awesome..  I did look at HAVING, but must have had the syntax wrong somewhere!
Interestingly, the initial query drags out 2254 rows in .782sec..  using having reduces it to 702, but now takes 1.095sec...

Comment: @BaronVonThierry . . . `HAVING` is not going to speed the query.  If performance is an issue, you might want to ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        `wpty_users`.`user_login` AS `user_login`,
        `wpty_users`.`display_name` AS `display_name`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`FIELD_ID` = 8 THEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`VALUE` ELSE NULL END) AS `Club`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`FIELD_ID` = 9 THEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`VALUE` ELSE NULL END) AS `State`
     FROM
        `wpty_users`
        LEFT JOIN `wpty_cimy_uef_data` ON `wpty_users`.`ID` = `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`USER_ID`
    GROUP BY `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`USER_ID`
    ORDER BY `wpty_users`.`user_login`
) x
WHERE `State` = 'SA'
```

Or better yet, you can use the column alias in a `HAVING` clause (as far as concerned, this is supported in MySQL):

```
SELECT
    `wpty_users`.`user_login` AS `user_login`,
    `wpty_users`.`display_name` AS `display_name`,
    MIN(CASE WHEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`FIELD_ID` = 8 THEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`VALUE` ELSE NULL END) AS `Club`,
    MIN(CASE WHEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`FIELD_ID` = 9 THEN `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`VALUE` ELSE NULL END) AS `State`
 FROM
    `wpty_users`
    LEFT JOIN `wpty_cimy_uef_data` ON `wpty_users`.`ID` = `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`USER_ID`
GROUP BY `wpty_cimy_uef_data`.`USER_ID`
HAVING `State` = 'SA'
ORDER BY `wpty_users`.`user_login`
```